# In tensorflow, how to iterate over a sequence of inputs stored in a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I am trying RNN on a variable length multivariate sequence classification problem.

I have defined following function to get the output of the sequence (i.e. the output of RNN cell after the final input from sequence is fed)

```
def get_sequence_output(x_sequence, initial_hidden_state):
    previous_hidden_state = initial_hidden_state
    for x_single in x_sequence:
        hidden_state = gru_unit(previous_hidden_state, x_single)
        previous_hidden_state = hidden_state
    final_hidden_state = hidden_state
    return final_hidden_state
```

Here `x_sequence` is tensor of shape `(?, ?, 10)` where first ? is for batch size and second ? is for sequence length and each input element is of length 10. `gru` function takes a previous hidden state and current input and spits out next hidden state (a standard gated recurrent unit).

I am getting an error: `'Tensor' object is not iterable.`
How do I iterate over a Tensor in sequence manner (reading single element at a time)?

My objective is to apply `gru` function for every input from the sequence and get the final hidden state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert a tensor into a list using the unpack function which converts the first dimension into a list.  There is also a split function which does something similar.  I use unstack in an RNN model I am working on.

```
y = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(y, (1, 0, 2)))
```

In this case y starts out with shape (BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS, 128)  I transpose it to make the time steps the outer dimension and then unpack it into a list of tensors, one per time step.  Now every element in the y list if of shape (BATCH_SIZE, 128) and I can feed it into my RNN.

Comment: This will not work if time_steps is not present(variable length of sequence).

Answer (score 10):

In TF>=1.0, `tf.pack` and `tf.unpack` are renamed to `tf.stack` and `tf.unstack` respectively